# Unexpected Server Error While Adding Realm in Keycloak on Docker Windows

Tags: json, docker, realm, keycloak

I configured Keycloak, using Docker and I was trying to a add a realm file in Keycloak dashboard, but I got this error:"An unexpected server error has occurred". Any idea how to solve this?

I got this. 
[image]

Comment: Please provide more info, such as the log messages prior to the error stated

Comment: I've just updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/cant-import-realm-using-docker-image/259), from Version 7.0.1 onwards Keycloak doesn’t allow uploading js scripts through admin endpoints/console and requires to be deployed in a similar fashion to Java providers. Try using another version.